# One-time binding to a random value generating method in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to hook up a temporary function for testing that returned a random date to display in my view. This was throwing errors because it got stuck in a loop, so I thought switching it to one-way binding would work, but the problem persists. The actual error is:

`[$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

When binding to a method call that returns a random value, why does Angular get stuck in an infinite loop? Shouldn't the expression stop evaluating once it's returned a value that isn't `undefined`?

Example [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/vRAl96NhXR5ZTP9nJEsx)

*Note: I'm not looking for a fix, I've already replaced the function call with a one-time generated random value, but I am curious to know why one-time binding continues to evaluate after the model should have (from my understanding) stabilized.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why this happens, you need to understand the digest cycle.

**Dirty Checking**

Angular is based on "dirty checking". 
Angular basically iterates over all properties in the `$scope` to see what has changed. If there is a change in any property, Angular fires all watchers for those properties to let them know about the change

And since a watch can change properties on the scope, Angular runs another round of dirty checking after the watches are done. The digestion cycle stops when it has iterated over all properties and it sees that none of them has changed.

An infinite digest occurs when a watch is always setting a new value to a property which is continously happening in `Math.random()`

Comment: So, one-way data binding has no effect on the digest cycle? I thought the idea behind it was to reduce the number of watchers.

Comment: No whatever is linked to $scope is continuously watched by angularJS. That is how the framework works